# Set chunksize dynamically after fetching from db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to set the chunk-size dynamically in a spring batch job's step which is stored in the database i.e the chunksize needs to be fetched from the database and set into the bean.

My Query is something like:

`select CHUNK_SIZE from SOME_TABLE_NAME where ID='some_id_param_value'`

Here the value for `ID` would come from the job parameters which is set via a request param passed with the request into the `Rest Controller`(while triggering the batch job)

I want to fetch this `CHUNK_SIZE` from the database and set it dynamically into the job's step.
Our requirement is that the chunksize varies for the step based on the ID value, the details of which are stored in a db table. For example:

| ID | CHUNK_SIZE |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1000 |
| 02 | 2500 |

I know that the beans in a job are set at the configuration time, and the job parameters are passed at the runtime while triggering the job.

**EDIT:**

The example provided by MahmoudBenHassine uses `@JobScope` and accesses the jobParameters in the step bean using `@Value("#{jobParameters['id']}")`. I tried implementing a similar approach using the `jobExecutionContext` as follows:

1. Fetched the chunkSize from the db table in the
   StepExecutionListener's `beforeStep` method and set it in the
   `ExecutionContext`.
2. Annotated the step bean with `@JobScope` and used
   `@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['chunk']}")` to access it in the step
   bean.
3. But I face the following error:

   `Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.step' defined in class path resource [com/sample/config/SampleBatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'step' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

It is not able to access the 'chunk' key-value from the `jobExecutionContext`, thus throwing the `NullPointerException`.
Does it need to be promoted somehow so that it can be accessed in the step bean? If yes, a quick sample or a direction would be really appreciated.

**My Controller class:**

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher sampleJobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    Job sampleJob;
    
    @GetMapping("/launch")
    public BatchStatus launch(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = true) String id){

        Map<String, JobParameter> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id",  new JobParameter(id));
        map.put("timestamp",  new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis));

        JobParameters params = new JobParameters(map);
        JobExecution j = sampleJobLauncher.run(sampleJob, params);

        return j.getStatus();
    }
}
```

**My batch config class(containing job and step bean):**

```
@Configuration
public class SampleBatchConfig{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory myJobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory myStepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepoClass myRepo; // this class contains the jdbc method to fetch chunksize from the db table
    
    @Autowired
    MyReader myReader;
    
    @Autowired
    MyWriter myWriter;
    
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step sampleStep(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['chunk']}") Integer chunkSize){
        return myStepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep")
                .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(chunkSize) //TODO ~instead of hardcoding the chunkSize or getting it from the properties file using @Value, the requirement is to fetch it from the db table using the above mentioned query with id job parameter and set it here
                .reader(myReader.sampleReader())
                .writer(myWriter.sampleWriter())
                .listener(new StepExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                        int chunk = myRepo.findChunkSize(stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("id")); // this method call fetches chunksize from the db table using the id job parameter
                        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("chunk", chunk);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(){
        return myJobBuilderFactory.get("sampleJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(sampleStep(null))
                .build();
    }

}
```

> **NOTE:
> The job may have multiple steps with different chunkSizes, and in that case chunkSize is to be fetched separately for each step.**

**EDIT 2:**
Changing my step definition as follows works, but there is a problem.
Here the reader reads a list having 17 items, in a chunk of size 4.

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step sampleStep(@Value("#{jobParameters['id']}") Integer id){
   int chunkSize = myRepo.findChunkSize(id); // this method call fetches chunksize from the db table using the id job parameter
   return myStepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep")
                .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(myReader.sampleReader())
                .writer(myWriter.sampleWriter())  
                .listener(new ChunkListenerSupport() {
                    @Override
                    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
                        System.out.println("MyJob.afterChunk");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
                        System.out.println("MyJob.beforeChunk");
                    }
                })                      
                .build();
}
```

The first time I trigger the job from the url, it works fine and prints the following: (The chunk Size is set to 4 in the db table)

```
2021-05-03 15:06:44.859  INFO 11924 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [sampleStep]
MyJob.beforeChunk

item = 1

item = 2

item = 3

item = 4

MyJob.afterChunk

MyJob.beforeChunk

item = 5

item = 6

item = 7

item = 8

MyJob.afterChunk

MyJob.beforeChunk

item = 9

item = 10

item = 11

item = 12

MyJob.afterChunk

MyJob.beforeChunk

item = 13

item = 14

item = 15

item = 16

MyJob.afterChunk

MyJob.beforeChunk

item = 17

MyJob.afterChunk
```

But if I trigger the job again, without restarting the server/spring container, the following is printed:

```
2021-05-03 15:11:02.427  INFO 11924 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [sampleStep]

MyJob.beforeChunk

MyJob.afterChunk
```

In Short, it works fine for exactly once, when the server is restarted. But it doesn't work for the subsequent job executions without restarting the server.

Comment: You can do that with a step-scoped or job-scoped bean. If you share the code of your controller and job/step definition with a TODO where you want to retrieve the chunk-size, I can provide an example, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1340#issuecomment-566276849

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I tried an approach based on your provided sample. But I face `NullPointerException`. I guess I'm missing something here. I've edited the question with the latest findings.

Comment: The example I shared takes the chunk size from job parameters and not from the execution context with a step execution listener. So saying that you followed the example and it did not work is not correct. Please update your description because now it feels like the example I shared does not work, while it does and I will answer your question with an example.

Comment: My bad. The example in the mentioned url works well. I meant to say I've tried implementing a similar approach using the `jobExecutionContext`. I've updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass the ID as a job parameter and you want to get the chunk size dynamically from the database based on that ID while configuring the step, you can use a job-scoped step as follows:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step sampleStep(@Value("#{jobParameters['id']}") Integer id){
   int chunkSize = myRepo.findChunkSize(id); // this method call fetches chunksize from the db table using the id job parameter
   return myStepBuilderFactory.get("sampleStep")
                .<MyClass, MyClass>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(myReader.sampleReader())
                .writer(myWriter.sampleWriter())                        
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This works fine. But can you please tell me if there's a way we can achieve this using the method followed in the question description.

Comment: It is not possible to use a listener because it's too late to configure the step in the listener. At that point the step has been already configured and started. What you are looking for is injecting the chunkSize dynamically at runtime while lazily configuring the step (ie before starting it and calling the listener around it).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But there's this behaviour it is showing which seems unexpected to me. I've added it in the question(Refer **EDIT 2** section). Can you please have a look?

Comment: What does `myReader.sampleReader()` in `.reader(myReader.sampleReader())`  return? Spring beans are singletons by default, so if you re-run your job the same instance of the reader will be used. You need to make your item reader step scoped.

Comment: It's the same reader from your example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1340#issuecomment-566276849 And using @StepScope on the reader worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. You're always of great help.

Comment: Also, can you please have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351093/write-to-a-file-in-transactional-manner