# Write to a file in transactional manner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-io, opencsv

I'm trying to **write/append** to a file in a springboot application.

My requirement is to rollback the **write/append** operation if an error occurs or anything goes wrong during the process.

I have two methods:

1. **Write to a csv file using the openCSV library** (Works fine as required i.e transactional behaviour)

```
public String writeStudentsToCSVFile(List<Student> students, String filePath){

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath,true);

    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy columnPositionMappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
    columnPositionMappingStrategy.setType(Student.class);

    String[] columns = new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName"};
    columnPositionMappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

    StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Student> beanToCsvBuilder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(fileWriter).withSeparator(',');
    StatefulBeanToCsv<Student> beanWriter = beanToCsvBuilder.withMappingStrategy(columnPositionMappingStrategy).build();
    
    students.forEach(student -> {
        beanWriter.write(student);
    });

    fileWriter.close();
    return "OK";
}
```

2. **Write to a flatfile using BufferedWriter** (TODO ~ implement transactional behaviour)

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String writeStudentsToFlatFile(List<Student> students, String filePath){

    BufferedWriter bw= Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath));
    
        students.forEach(student -> {
            bw.write(student.toString());
            bw.newLine();
        });

    bw.close();
    return "OK";
}
```

The `writeStudentsToCSVFile` works perfectly fine, in a transactional manner(in an atomic way) i.e if something went wrong at 10th record, it won't write any of the first 9 records to the output file. I want to achieve this similar behaviour in the method 2 aswell.

The problem is with the second method `writeStudentsToFlatFile`. I tried to make it transactional by adding the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation. But it still doesn't work. For example, If the 10th record was  bad record, the first 9 records would be written to the file nonetheless. My requirement is for it to not write any of the records of the input list to the file (i.e rollback the records processed till the point of error i.e transactional behaviour)

**EDIT:**

I have found the following workaround for time being:

Instead of writing each element of the list individually, I added up all the elements to make it into a huge string by using the `StringBuilder` and appending `lineSeparator` at the end of each individual element. And thus write this constructed String into the file at once.

**I. Using BufferedWriter:**

```
public String writeStudentsToFlatFile1(List<Student> students, String filePath){

    BufferedWriter bw= Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath));
    
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    
    students.forEach(student -> {
        strb.append(student.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
    });

    bw.write(strb.toString());
    bw.close();
    return "OK";
}
```

**II. I've also implemented the same using nio `FileChannel`:**

```
public String writeStudentsToFlatFile2(List<Student> students, String filePath){

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
    FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
    
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Student student : students){
            strb.append(student.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(strb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
    channel.position(channel.size());
    channel.write(buffer);

    channel.close();
    file.close();

    return "OK";
}
```

**Requirement:**
*But I am looking for a way to achieve this atomic behaviour without making a huge String out of all the elements.(As it is done in the `writeStudentsToCSVFile` method mentioned above which is using open CSV)*

**III.** I came across [TransactionAwareBufferedWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/support/transaction/TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.html) from `Spring Batch`, and tried a sample implementation but couldn't make it work.

```
public String writeStudentsToFlatFile3(List<Student> list, String filePath){

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

    FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    TransactionAwareBufferedWriter writer = new TransactionAwareBufferedWriter(channel, null);

    for (Student student : list){
            strb.append(element.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

    writer.append(strb.toString());

    writer.close();
    channel.close();
    file.close();

    return "OK";
}
```

If this method `writeStudentsToFlatFile3` is called in a loop for the same `filePath` it throws this error after the first iteration:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.close(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]`

It could have something to do with closing the resource using the `Runnable` argument.

Comment: I believe you are confusing the effects of output buffering with "transactional behavior".  There is nothing transactional about OpenCSV or BufferedWriter.  What makes you think this is the case? Also, what kinds of "errors" do you want to cause a rollback?  If you want rollback with simple files you will need to implement it yourself by keeping track of the file output location at the start and truncating back to that position to perform a rollback.

Comment: As a side note, using a `FileChannel` might be more convenient for your transactional use case

Comment: @JimGarrison My bad. I might've used the incorrect terms. In short, my requirement is -> **Either the whole list should be written(appended) into the file, or no element of the list should be written(in case there is an exception). Atomicity**. I've updated the question with the current workaround I'm using.

Comment: @crizzis I've updated my question with a workaround that i found. Also added the implementation using `FileChannel`. Please have a look and let me know if there's a way it can be achieved without adding up all the elements of the list into a huge String.

Comment: The problem is that there are several layers between your code and the file, and any of them can fail for various reasons.  If you want to make a write atomic you must either use an existing atomic library class (it’s not clear what the Spring class does from the Javadoc) or implement your own: save file pointer; write; if exception truncate back to old file pointer. And you can still end up corrupted if your program is `kill -9`ed by the user or OS.  To guarantee atomicity you’d have to keep the file pointer in its own file and verify against the actual file length on open to detect this.

Comment: In short, atomicity in the file system is HARD.

Comment: You could use a transactional file system (e.g. [this](https://github.com/ut-osa/txfs)) rather than trying to manipulate single files in a transactional way.